# Grails 3 throwing strange exception when using more than 14 Domain classes with @Resource

Tags: grails

Grails 3 is throwing a strange exception when using REST Resources.  What I have noticed is that when I have more than 14 Domain classes with the `@Resource` annotation it is throw a weird exception and refuses to start with the run-app command.  I have checked in code to a github repo to demonstrate the problem.  If you get this project and do a grails run-app it will throw an exception.  I am using **JDK 7** and **grails 3.0.4**.

Github repo:  https://github.com/akhopkar/testREST

The Exception it throws is:

```
ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.test.A2Controller': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
```

Comment: as the repo contents can change and wouldnt help anyone in the future, could you please post the code here that is relevant?

Comment: The repo contents are not going to change.  I have created this repo to specifically demonstrate this problem.  Anyway... all I have in that project is 14 domain classes that look like this:

Comment: package com.test

import grails.rest.Resource

@Resource(uri='/as', formats=['json', 'xml'])
class A {

    static constraints = {
    }
}

Comment: Ok the problem is solved from grails 3.0.2 onwards.  I installed grails 3.0.4 and change the grails version in gradle.properties to 3.0.4 and now it is working fine.

Comment: The problem was that I created this project with grails 3.0.1 i.e. I was using grails 3.0.1 when I fired create-app.  Subsequently I started using grails 3.0.4, but since the app was initially created with 3.0.1 the gradle.properties still had the value 3.0.1 so it wasn't working.  Now, that I changed that property, it is working fine.